# Pycharm - Tag Completion on Space

Tags: pycharm

This is so annoying.

I started working and for some strange reason, space completes the html tags instead of tab.

For example, I type some string, say `string`, and hit space and it turns into:
`<string></string>`. But if I type `div` and hit tab, it just adds whitespace.

> **PyCharm Version**
>
> PyCharm 2020.1.1 (Professional Edition)
>
> Build #PY-201.7223.92, built on April 30, 2020
>
> Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.40 amd64

Answer (score 0):

Well, I looked everywhere but did not find any setting related to this (maybe I missed something).

But I fixed it by Restoring Default Setting. I think it was due to some plugins I installed but could not figure out which one. So, I just Restored the default setting.

`File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings...`

This will set your IDE to the vanilla IDE.